# PHP - CSV File is being overwritten

Tags: php, csv

**Edit: Fixed the password problem**

I'm dealing with a small issue. I'm trying to write to a .csv file to store output I'm getting for crypt() output. I'm looking for baseline security as this will be held locally on my LAN, I just wanted to use crypt() to start to learn how to use it. The issue I'm having is that the first line of the .csv is being overwritten each time I attempt to add a new user. Here's the code, feel free to mess around with it, and thank you all in advance! (oh, and the password is not being compared correctly, I'll be working on that throughout as well)

```
    <?php
    $usr = $_GET['user'];
    $pass = $_GET['pass'];
    $salt = '$2a$07$jjskdkwidjfjvjfjskalclzjohwuvnounbfonwfnwgnwlfjn';
    $c_usr = crypt($usr,$salt);
    $c_pass = crypt($pass,$salt);
    echo $usr . ' - ' . $c_usr;
    echo "<br>" . $pass . ' - ' . $c_pass;
    if (file_exists('test.csv')) {
        echo '<br>file exists';
        $csvFile = file('test.csv');
        $data = [];
        $c = 0;
        foreach ($csvFile as $line) {
            $data[] = str_getcsv($line);
            list($r_usr,$r_pwd) = split(" - ", implode(" ", $data[$c]));
            if ($r_usr === $c_usr) {
                echo "<br>user in database";
                if ($r_pwd === $c_pass) {
                    echo "<br> password correct";
                } else {
                    echo "<br> incorrect password";
                }
            } else {
                echo "user not in database";
                $data = array(
                    $c_usr . ' - ' . $c_pass
                );
                $fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
                foreach ( $data as $line ) {
                    $val = explode(",", $line);
                    fputcsv($fp, $val);
                }
                fclose($fp);
                echo "user now in database";
            }
            $c++;
        }
    } else {
        $data = array(
                $c_usr . ' - ' . $c_pass
        );
        $fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
        foreach ( $data as $line ) {
            $val = explode(",", $line);
            fputcsv($fp, $val);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

and here is what I put in the menubar:

```
http://localhost/?user=bob&pass=1234
```

Comment: You'll want to use `fopen('test.csv', 'a');` Your `w` directive places the file pointer at the beginning of the file, regardless of what is there. `a` (append) will place the file pointer at the end of the file. Make sure you write a newline at the end of each of your entries, or else they'll bunch up on the first line only.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly!